# div's in a box arrangement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I spent a lot of time trying to do this:

[image]

The black square is a `div` (doesn't have to be a `div`) `container`.

All the other squares are `div`s or `span`s or whatever (its not the issue)

Can someone direct me how to accomplish this using plain HTML, CSS and Javascript?

*I tried to make all squares `div`s but then because in one line their is a square with different height the next line will be with missing 'parts' and then tried to manage this issue with margin- but it didn't work out and I am sure its not that difficult.

Comment: i tried to do it serval times.. and now i tried again and didnt come out with nothing(in mind) because of the last times i tried.. so no i didnt even tried this now.. i can write something and try but it wont be clean ill just play with it like the last time i tried and got nothing:\

Comment: What flexibility do you have? Is the number of items fixed? Do you know the number of items in advance? Do you know the item heights in advance? Depending on these answers, it might be easiest to build this column-by-column rather than row-by-row and avoid the positioning problem altogether.

Comment: can you draw this using HTML 5 canvas???I mean is that fine for you?? or you dont want to use any HTML 5 tags

Comment: no not html5 its need to be cross-broswer

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Y5GDg/1/ its supported is almost all the browsers now except I think IE7/8....canvas is the container where you can draw any shape as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try absolute positioning:

```
<style>
.rect {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px ;
    height: 200px;
}

</style>
<div class="rect" style="top:0;left:0;border:3px solid blue"></div>
<div class="rect" style="top:206px;left:0;border:3px solid green"></div>
<div class="rect" style="top:0;left:106px;border:3px solid red; height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: this should be accomplished using either id's or pseudo classes. It is depreciated to use in-element styling

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is the CSS3 property `column-count`. It displays the number of columns inside any sort of container. So if you were trying to use this as a picture album

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap:   0px;
-moz-column-count:    3;
-moz-column-gap:      0px;
column-count:         3;
column-gap:           0px;

}
#photos img {
/* Just in case there are inline attributes */
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}
```

Where #photos would be you're container. 

Credit to Chris Coyier for the article http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: thanks it is simple using css3, but i needed it to be cross-browser.

Comment: that is what the prefixers are for. it works in all browsers... besides internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no code to show us I won't do the code for you... But I can tell you what might be usefull for this.

Here are some css parameters that can help you to achieve this :

- `position`
- `margin`
- `display`
- `float`

Every square in this should be a `DIV` and a good combo of these should do the trick!

Comment: i really dont want to copy & paste some code for squares its some question that i was asked during a job interview and didnt manage to accomplish.. and i really want to avoid such difficulties in future and work on some good **base** for this..

Comment: I really don't get what you mean.. whith this desing you don't really have the choice to have a unique css id for each one of them.

Comment: and why "Every square in this should be a DIV"? and not a span?

Comment: well div should be considered as containers for content such as the menu, the banner or the adds and a span is division within the content itself like dividing the title of an article from the text.